# Error in equation- latex

Tags: equations

[image]

Hi, I want to write the equation (above) as it is, in latex. So far I have this :

```
\begin{multline}\label{EEDIeq}
\frac{\Bigg(\prod_{j=1}^n f_j\Bigg) 
    \Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{nME}P_{ME(i)}.C_{FME(i)}.SFC_{ME(i)}\Bigg) + 
        (P_{AE}.C_{FAE}.SFC_{AE})+ \\
    \Bigg(\Bigg(\prod_{j=1}^n f_j.\sum_{i=1}^{nPTI} P_{PTI(i)}-
    \sum_{i=1}^{neff}f_{eff(i)}.P_{AEeff(i)}\Bigg) C_{FAE}.SFC_{AE}\Bigg) -\\ 
    \Bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{neff}f_{eff(i)}.P_{eff(i)}.C_{FME}.SFC_{ME}\Bigg)}{f_i.f_c.f_l.Capacity.f_w.V_{ref}}
\end{multline}
```

But this gives me an error. How can i fix this?

Comment: You don't seriously want to make it fit in a single line?

Comment: Haha, well I want to put it in my report, Do you have any other suggestions as to how I can write this in my report?

Comment: Instead of writing it as a single fraction, you could write it on the form 1/x * (some long expression that may contain line breaks).

Comment: What are all these ME, FAE, SFC,&c.? Some seem to be variables, others functions or operators. Could you explain some details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some unwanted enter marks caused the issue, below is the updated code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

   \begin{multline}\label{EEDIeq}
\frac{\Biggl(\prod_{j=1}^n f_j\Biggr) 
    \Biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{nME}P_{ME(i)}.C_{FME(i)}.SFC_{ME(i)}\Biggr) + 
        (P_{AE}.C_{FAE}.SFC_{AE})+ 
    \Biggl(\Biggl(\prod_{j=1}^n f_j.\sum_{i=1}^{nPTI} P_{PTI(i)}-
    \sum_{i=1}^{neff}f_{eff(i)}.P_{AEeff(i)}\Biggr)
    C_{FAE}.SFC_{AE}\Biggr) -
    \Biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{neff}f_{eff(i)}.P_{eff(i)}.C_{FME}.SFC_{ME}\Biggr)}{f_i.f_c.f_l.Capacity.f_w.V_{ref}}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

But confirm that really you want this equation in a same line?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Corrected, thanks...

Comment: Thanks for the updates code. Yes, I do want it in the same line

Comment: @MadyYuvi Hi, have you tried to use `geometry` package to increase the margins or decrease the size of the characters `\documentclass[10]{...}`? Good work.

Comment: Yes, that helps. I decreased the font size. Thanks!

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for your note...

Comment: @MadyYuvi It's always a pleasure for me :-)